# JSON checking for constrains

Tags: javascript, json

To give some context to this, the following JSON code represents transitions between edges. In this case, we have `a, b and c` as states,  and  `0, 1` as transition values.

For example, `["a", "b", ["0"]]` means that from `a` one can transition to `b` with the value `0`.

I have to make sure that for every state, both transition values are presents. Which means that, from `a` it should be possible to transition with either `1 or 0` value, which also should be true for `b and c`.

How can I write a function which goes though the JSON code below and checks whether or not if it is true, that I can transition with either one of the transition values?

`"edges": [["a", "a", ["1"]], ["a", "b", ["0"]], ["b", "a", ["1"]], ["b", "c", ["0"]], ["c", "c", ["0", "1"]]]`

Comment: Can you provide a clear example of the input and output desired from the function ?

Comment: Well, it might actually be more of a method than a function actually. Since its a method of a class that I am currently building, so there aren't really any input parameters . The JSON code is output from another function, which this method then reads. 

But this method is suppose to be a boolean, so in this case it should return true.

Comment: can you provide the list of the rules to all the possible transitions ?

Comment: The only rule is that, depending on size of the transition values, a state can only have that amount of out going transitions. 
So for example, since my transition values are `0, 1`then every state `a, b and c` has to have two out going transitions.